# Dropdown CSS issue - hidden list shows up when hovered over

Tags: html, css

my problem is that when I hover over the area where the hidden list is, it shows the hidden list. I only want it to show the hidden list when hovered over the 'Language' link on the dropdown menu. Why is it doing this, it's probably something blindingly obvious that I can't spot.

Cheers :)

EDIT: I've already tried using a fixed height for the #lang_bar. I also need the transitions to still work. I've already tried using the display:none and display:block; but that didn't work so I used visibility instead.

Any ideas?

HTML:

```
        <div id="lang_bar">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#"><strong>Language</strong></a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href ="#"><strong>Maori</strong></a></li>
                    <li><a href ="#"><strong>Tongan</strong></a></li>
                    <li><a href ="#"><strong>Chinese</strong></a></li>
                    <li><a href ="#"><strong>Japanese</strong></a></li>
                    <li><a href ="#"><strong>Korean</strong></a></li>
                </ul>
            </ul>
    </div>
```

```css
#lang_bar {

    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    color: white;
    padding-left: 152px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    z-index: 40;
    position: absolute;
    padding-top: 2px;
    top: 0;

}


#lang_bar ul ul li a {

    padding-top: 3px;
    padding-left:5px;

}


#lang_bar ul li ul li a:before {

    content: '';
    display:block;
    right: 0px;
    height: 2px;
    bottom:117px;
    width: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);

}

#lang_bar ul li ul li a:after {
    content: '';
    display:block;
    right: 1px;
    height: 2px;
    width: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);

}

#lang_bar li, #lang_bar li ul {


    text-decoration: none;
    list-style-type: none;

}

#lang_bar ul {

    list-style: none;
    padding-left: 0px;

}

#lang_bar ul li {

    float: left;
    width: 100px;
    text-align: left;
    line-height: 21px;

}

#lang_bar ul li a {

    display: block;
        color: #FFF;
        background: transparent;
        text-decoration: none;
        text-align: center;

}

#lang_bar ul li ul {

        visibility: hidden;
        font-size:12px;
        opacity: 0;

}

#lang_bar ul li:hover ul {

        opacity: 1;

        visibility: visible; /* display the dropdown */
        -webkit-transition: all .25s ease;
        -moz-transition: all .25s ease;
        -ms-transition: all .25s ease;
        -o-transition: all .25s ease;
        transition: all .25s ease;

}

#lang_bar ul li ul a:hover{
        transition-duration: 0.6s;
        background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.23);

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about just using the adjacent sibling combinator:

Change: #lang_bar ul li:hover ul

To: #lang_bar ul li a:hover + ul

Comment: You're amazing. I knew it was something as silly as that! Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

I changed your css a little bit and here is the result

I used display:none and display: block in place of visibility, and everything is working as it should be.

http://jsfiddle.net/sy3qowxs/5/[enter link description here](http://jsfiddle.net/sy3qowxs/5/)

And here is your final CSS:

```
#lang_bar {

    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    color: #123111;
    padding-left: 152px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    z-index: 40;
    position: absolute;
    padding-top: 2px;
    top: 0;

}
#lang_bar a:link{color:#333333;}


#lang_bar ul ul li a {

    padding-top: 3px;
    padding-left:5px;

}


#lang_bar ul li ul li a:before {

    content: '';
    display:block;
    right: 0px;
    height: 2px;
    bottom:117px;
    width: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);

}

#lang_bar ul li ul li a:after {
    content: '';
    display:block;
    right: 1px;
    height: 2px;
    width: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);

}

#lang_bar li, #lang_bar li ul {


    text-decoration: none;
    list-style-type: none;

}

#lang_bar ul {

    list-style: none;
    padding-left: 0px;

}

#lang_bar ul li {

    float: left;
    width: 100px;
    text-align: left;
    line-height: 21px;

}

#lang_bar ul li a {

    display: block;
        color: #FFF;
        background: transparent;
        text-decoration: none;
        text-align: center;

}

#lang_bar ul li ul {

        display: none;
        font-size:12px;
        opacity: 0;

}

#lang_bar ul li:hover ul {

        opacity: 1;

        display: block; /* display the dropdown */
        -webkit-transition: all .25s ease;
        -moz-transition: all .25s ease;
        -ms-transition: all .25s ease;
        -o-transition: all .25s ease;
        transition: all .25s ease;

}

#lang_bar ul li ul a:hover{
        transition-duration: 0.6s;
        background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.23);

    }
```

Comment: I already used the display : none and display:block code but it removed my transitions and animations. That's why I was using the visibility instead. I already had the code working but the transitions didn't work with this code.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to the display: none solution, for [accessibility reasons](http://webaim.org/techniques/css/invisiblecontent/) you can use position:absolute and then move the hidden element off screen:

```
ul li ul {
    position:absolute;
    top:-1000px;
}

ul li:hover ul {
    top:auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It should work with `visibility`, since it hides the element (like `display: none`) but doesn't remove it from the DOM

Here is a working example: [Dropdown Menu](http://codepen.io/mallendeo/pen/LryGt)

HTML

```
<ul class="menu">
  <li class="menu-item"> <a href="#">Dropdown Menu</a>
    <ul class="submenu">
      <li class="submenu-item"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
      <li class="submenu-item"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
      <li class="submenu-item"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
      <li class="submenu-item"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
      <li class="submenu-item"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
.menu-item {
  position: relative;
}

.menu-item:hover .submenu {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}

.submenu {
  position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: all .2s ease;
  opacity: 0;
  top: 100%;
}

.submenu-item {
  padding: .4em;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To add to the previous answer, the reason this works when you use the display property instead of visibility is because display removes the element from the document flow, and other elements reflow in its place. Visibility, on the other hand, hides the element, but leaves the empty space as if it were still there.  So when you used visibility: hidden, your list item looked like it just contained the text "Language" and the link, but the hidden ul was still there, and still hoverable. That's why when you hovered over where the list item should have been, it reappeared; technically, you were hovering over that first list item, because the sub menu was a child of it.

In general, I use display:block/display:none to toggle hiding and showing of items, rather than visibility. Typically the use case is that you want the element completely hidden from the page, and elements around it to reflow, and the display property will do that for you.

Comment: Hmmm is there a work around for adding the transitions to work with display:none and block?

Comment: Unfortunately, that's a bit more complex; the display property is not one of the supported properties allowed in [CSS transitions](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transitions/#animatable-properties). There are some workarounds, though; maybe try [this](http://www.impressivewebs.com/animate-display-block-none/)?